# Set git branch or tag name to packed jar

Tags: git, maven

I have a project with this three commits.

```
commit e0a31e1a9e6aaff7ed40533873f1a7c35d0257a9 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
commit 0e0d53afd5a2282a0d4c0c2b6a15edaad53f4541 (tag: v1)
commit f7c3b39831d01c77933a7c62341af030c63c0b97
```

This project is made with maven and is packed with `maven-jar-plugin` plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

I am also having this project in a git reposity, so I added `git-commit-id-plugin` to get the git revisions. I also need the `replacementProperties` from the plugin to replace `/` in my branchname with `-`.

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
              <goals>
                  <goal>revision</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>initialize</phase>
          </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
          <gitDescribe>
            <tags>true</tags>
          </gitDescribe>
          <replacementProperties>
              <replacementProperty>
                 <property>git.branch</property>
                 <token>^([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$</token>
                 <value>$1-$2</value>
                 <regex>true</regex>
                 <forceValueEvaluation>false</forceValueEvaluation>
                 <transformationRules>
                   <transformationRule>
                     <apply>BEFORE</apply>
                     <action>UPPER_CASE</action>
                   </transformationRule>
                   <transformationRule>
                     <apply>AFTER</apply>
                     <action>LOWER_CASE</action>
                   </transformationRule>
                 </transformationRules>
               </replacementProperty>
          </replacementProperties>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In my `pom.xml` I was adding the version as followed:

```
<version>_${git.branch}_${git.tags}</version>
```

When I was on commit  `0e0d53afd5a2282a0d4c0c2b6a15edaad53f4541` (my tag) I was getting the jar with then name`artifact-_0e0d53afd5a2282a0d4c0c2b6a15edaad53f4541_v1.jar`.

When I was on commit `e0a31e1a9e6aaff7ed40533873f1a7c35d0257a9` (current head) I was getting the jar with the name `artifact-_master_.jar`.

I was also trying `${git.commit.id.describe}` for the version. It was not giving me the desired result.

My desired output is:

1. When I have checked out a tag, I want the in filename my tag, eg. `artifact-v1.jar`.
2. When I have checked out a branch, no matter if HEAD or not, I want in the filename my branch, eg. `artifact-master.jar`.

I know that I can achieve the 2. use case by having `<version>${git.branch}</version>` as my version, but it will ruin my tags.

What can I do to have both use cases work together?

Comment: Why do you want this? Why not "normal" version numbers like `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Because I don't want the edit my pom everytime i make a new tag / branch and want to see the tag / branch directly from the jar.